# OpenJDK 8 (1.8.0_151) in Docker HTTPS connection issue to IIS server

Tags: java, docker, ssl, iis, soap

I'am trying to invoke SOAP service, hosted on IIS server (version unknown) from java application inside Docker container. Added CE certificate to JDK cert store. Also there is a proxy server in our corporate network. IIS server located in private network, so I added JDK proxy CLI parameters to go through proxy to internet and bypass proxy for private network. Communication with internet over HTTPS is fine, but invoking IIS server I always receive such error:

```
Telegram Executor, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 179, 239, 20, 68, 62, 114, 149, 9, 213, 8, 166, 3 }
***
Telegram Executor, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 40
Telegram Executor, READ: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
Telegram Executor, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 40
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 188, 169, 41, 148, 80, 6, 90, 100, 144, 226, 166, 42 }
***
%% Cached client session: [Session-6, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384]
Telegram Executor, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Application Data, length = 676
Telegram Executor, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Application Data, length = 772
Telegram Executor, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
%% Invalidated:  [Session-6, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384]
Telegram Executor, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
Telegram Executor, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 26
Telegram Executor, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
Telegram Executor, called closeSocket()
Telegram Executor, called close()
Telegram Executor, called closeInternal(true)
Mar 19, 2018 9:26:13 AM org.telegram.telegrambots.logging.BotLogger severe
SEVERE: BOTSESSION
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.readResponseCodeAndMessage(HttpClientTransport.java:195)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.createResponsePacket(HttpTransportPipe.java:226)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:217)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:130)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:124)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1121)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1035)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1004)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:862)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:448)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:178)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:93)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:77)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:147)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.getUserInfo(Unknown Source)
        at isd.bot.commands.TimeClockSecureCommand.timeClockLoginHandler(TimeClockSecureCommand.java:89)
        at isd.bot.commands.TimeClockSecureCommand.execute(TimeClockSecureCommand.java:59)
        at isd.bot.DefaultUpdateHandler.accept(DefaultUpdateHandler.java:49)
        at isd.bot.DefaultUpdateHandler.accept(DefaultUpdateHandler.java:16)
        at isd.bot.IsdTelegramLongPollingBotImpl.onUpdateReceived(IsdTelegramLongPollingBotImpl.java:43)
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1255)
        at org.telegram.telegrambots.generics.LongPollingBot.onUpdatesReceived(LongPollingBot.java:27)
        at org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.DefaultBotSession$HandlerThread.run(DefaultBotSession.java:311)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:940)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:735)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:678)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:706)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1587)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:347)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.readResponseCodeAndMessage(HttpClientTransport.java:191)
        ... 22 more
```

The same service works fine from .NET application.
Could you please advice what can be the problem?

Java side code:

```
ITimeClockServer service = new TimeClockServer().getWSHttpBindingITimeClockServer();
((BindingProvider)result).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, BotProperties.getInstance().getTimeClockEndpoint());
((BindingProvider)result).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, BotProperties.getInstance().getUserLogin());
((BindingProvider)result).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, BotProperties.getInstance().getUserPassword());
TimeClockUserInfo userInfo = service.getUserInfo(login);
```

Comment: Try a CURL or WGET to access your IIS server, then we are sure it's not a network issue.

Comment: 'curl -k ${service.wsdl.location}' works as well.

Comment: Could you perhaps add the java code that is calling the service?

Comment: Added java side code. Please take a look.